# Azure spring boot function-how to pass trigger and input binding both to handleRequest method at same time?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-functions, spring-cloud-function

```
package com.att.trace.function;

import java.util.Optional;

import com.att.trace.function.model.User;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.ExecutionContext;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpMethod;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpRequestMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpResponseMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpStatus;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.AuthorizationLevel;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.BlobInput;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.HttpTrigger;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.StorageAccount;

import org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.FunctionInvoker;

import reactor.util.function.Tuple2;
import reactor.util.function.Tuples;

public class HelloHandler extends FunctionInvoker<Tuple2<User, String>, String> {

        @FunctionName("hello")
        @StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")
        public HttpResponseMessage execute(@HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = { HttpMethod.GET,
                        HttpMethod.POST }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<User>> request,
                        @BlobInput(name = "requestjsonblob", dataType = "string", path = "requestjson/{name}.json") String requestjson,
                        ExecutionContext context) {
                User user = request.getBody().get();
                System.out.println("requestjson=" + requestjson);
                Tuple2<User, String> input = Tuples.of(user, requestjson);
                handleRequest(input, context);
                return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("ok")
                                .header("Content-Type", "application/json").build();
        }
}


package com.att.trace.function;

import java.util.function.Function;

import com.att.trace.function.model.User;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import reactor.util.function.Tuple2;

@Component
public class Hello implements Function<Tuple2<User, String>, String> {
  public String apply(Tuple2<User, String> objects) {
    System.out.println("objects.getT1()=" + objects.getT1());
    System.out.println("objects.getT2()=" + objects.getT2());
    String output = "test output";
    return output;

  }
}
```

getting below exception when I create tuple of Http trigger and blobinput and send it to handleRequest..

[2021-08-20T09:53:12.816Z] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: At the moment only Tuple-based function are supporting multiple arguments
[2021-08-20T09:53:12.818Z]      at

I need to send both inputs to handleRequest method... any clue how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent some time and the only way I could achieve that what you want is by using DTO class.

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class HelloInputArguments {
    private User user;
    private String content;
}
```

Then handler is easy

```
package com.example.demo;


import com.example.demo.model.HelloInputArguments;
import com.example.demo.model.User;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.FunctionInvoker;

import java.util.Optional;


public class HelloHandler extends FunctionInvoker<HelloInputArguments, String> {

    @FunctionName("hello")
    @StorageAccount("DefaultConnection")
    public HttpResponseMessage execute(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<User>> request,
            @BlobInput(name = "file", dataType = "string", path = "requestjson/proam.json") String content,
            ExecutionContext context) {
        User user = request.getBody().get();

        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(handleRequest(new HelloInputArguments(user, content), context))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();
    }
}
```

And function

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.model.HelloInputArguments;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.function.Function;

@Component
public class Hello implements Function<HelloInputArguments, String> {
    public String apply(HelloInputArguments input) {
      return input.getContent();
    }
}
```

I thin with Tuple are allowed only if you want to pass multiple Fluxs [in doc](https://spring.io/blog/2019/08/15/announcing-spring-cloud-function-3-0-0-m2)

Comment: thanks Vova! agreed. that's one of the option. let me try and get back.

Comment: @TarunkumarAghara How it goes ?:)

Comment: thanks @Vova.. Tried just now . yes using DTO works ok... did not get chance to check `I thin with Tuple are allowed only if you want to pass multiple Fluxs in doc`  --- will try it later and confirm back

Comment: I submitted one more question related to azure function at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68863759/azure-spring-boot-function-how-to-send-multiple-outputbinding-to-handleoutput    I would really appreciate if you can take a look and suggest when you find sometime... @Vova

Comment: I tried with `public class HelloTupleHandler
                extends FunctionInvoker<Tuple2<Flux<User>, Flux<String>>, Tuple2<Flux<String>, Flux<String>>> {`  but it didnt work - throws At the moment only Tuple-based function are supporting multiple arguments exception