# Azure spring boot function - how to send multiple OutputBinding to handleOutput method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-functions

```
  @FunctionName("scheduleRunning")
    @StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")
    public void execute(
            // function triggers and executes every three minutes.
            @TimerTrigger(name = "keepAliveTrigger", schedule = "0 */3 * * * *") String timerInfo,
            @QueueOutput(name = "jobSucceeded", queueName = "job-succeeded") OutputBinding<String> jobSucceeded,
            @QueueOutput(name = "jobFailed", queueName = "job-failed") OutputBinding<String> jobFailed,ExecutionContext context) {
            
            String input="test";
            //handleOutput(input, jobSucceeded, context);
            }
```

how can I pass jobSucceeded and jobFailed both to handleOutput method?

Answer (score 0):

you need to call method `setValue()`

```
@FunctionName("scheduleRunning")
    @StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")
    public void execute(
            // function triggers and executes every three minutes.
            @TimerTrigger(name = "keepAliveTrigger", schedule = "0 */3 * * * *") String timerInfo,
            @QueueOutput(name = "jobSucceeded", queueName = "job-succeeded") OutputBinding<String> jobSucceeded,
            @QueueOutput(name = "jobFailed", queueName = "job-failed") OutputBinding<String> jobFailed,ExecutionContext context) {
            
            String input="test";
            jobSucceeded.setValue(input);
            jobFailed.setValue("Other message")
  }
```

You can find other [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=java)

Or you can also create new pojo which will help you to path your **jobSucceeded** and **jobFailed** objects, and then in your function you can keep your logic and call **setValue** methonds

Comment: thanks ! `jobSucceeded.setValue(input);
            jobFailed.setValue("Other message")` I do same as of today but  I want to send both to handleOutput and keep minimum code in functions execute method. let me try POJO

Comment: @TarunkumarAghara how it goes?:)

Comment: I could not make it work. not sure how to create  and assign values to OutputBinding<Tuple2<OutputBinding<String>, OutputBinding<String>>> object or POJO  of OutputBinding<String>